# how to use plutil to edit a key-value pair of a dictionary contained by an array in .plist file

Tags: ios, dictionary

I am learning to use the command plutil to edit .plist files. I've got this problem: If I want to edit a dictionary's key-value pair inside an array, what should I do with the `keypath`?
The file content looks like this:

```
[heping@Totoro:~ 17:10]# plutil -p /Users/heping/Desktop/test.plist
{
   "array" => [
    0 => {
      "weight" => 153
      "name" => "pig"
    }
    1 => {
      "weight" => 3
      "name" => "cat"
    }
  ]
}
```

I try to retrieve the first item's `name`, successfully I got this:

```
[heping@Totoro:~ 17:13]# plutil -extract array.0.name xml1 -o - -- /Users/heping/Desktop/test.plist
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<string>pig</string>
</plist>
```

But when I try to replace the first item's `name`, I get an error and I just cannot understand why this happened.

```
[heping@Totoro:~ 17:17]# plutil -replace array.0.name -string piglet       /Users/heping/Desktop/test.plist
/Users/heping/Desktop/test.plist: Could not modify plist, error: Failed to insert value piglet at key path array.0.name with error -[NSTaggedPointerString characterAtIndex:]: Index 0 out of bounds; string length 0
```

Comment: Please don't post text in screenshots. They can't be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: @Chris I've corrected the style of my question. Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: @laucel No, not yet.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to input "piglet" in inverted commas. It should work that way.

Comment: I did as you told me to do, but still failed with the same error.  Whoops ~